# How could I send a React.js component from my node.js to my client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, components, ejs

I'm sending a client a loader, and I want to receive my main React.js components from the server, after rendering the loader.

I'm using node.js with express on the backend and i'm using the "express-react-views" engine for rendering.

So, how can I safely transfer components from the server to the client?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The script tag in html downloads your js file with all the components, which is the default way. Isn't that sufficient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var htmlOfComponent = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(component);
```

1. send this htmlOfComponent as part of your initial html page
   request from server.
2. include react.js in script tags and send.
3. For component data=> you can send that stringified in script tags
       too.